# Add tabs to actionbar via XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I know that it is possible to add MenuItems to the ActionBar using a XML file in /res/menu directory.

I have been looking for an example of how to add Tabs to the ActionBar using a XML without any success.

I only found a way to do this calling: actionbar.newTab() method but I would not like to do this in code...

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this, sorry. You can only define tabs in the action bar via Java code.

Answer (score 1):

in array.xml:

```
<string-array name="actionBarTabs">
    <item>tab1</item>
    <item>tab2</item>
    <item>tab3</item>        
</string-array>
```

---

```
onCreate() {

    // setup action bar for tabs
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    for (String each:getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actionBarTabs)) {
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(each)
                .setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);              
    }     
}
```

Comment: your array should be in arrays.xml